# java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to org.springframework.amqp.core.Message

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I used spring-cloud-stream & spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit that's version is 3.2.4.
When I used deadLetterQueue it work on well.When I used batchMode it work on well too. But when I used them together there were some Exception came out.

my configuration like this:

```
spring
  cloud:
    stream:
      rabbit:
        bindings:
          fundNotice-in-0:
            consumer:
              bindQueue: false
              declareExchange: false
              queueNameGroupOnly: true
              bindingRoutingKey: abc2repeat-queue-test-key
              autoBindDlq: false
              deadLetterExchange: abc2repeat-dlq-exchange
              deadLetterRoutingKey: abc2repeat-dlq-key
              deadLetterQueueName: abc2repeat-dlq-queue
              dlqMaxLength: 10000
              dlqMaxLengthBytes: 1048576
              enableBatching: true
              batchSize: 5
              receiveTimeout: 10000
      ......
      ......
      bindings:
        fundNotice-in-0:
          destination: abc2repeat-direct
          group: abc2repeat-queue-test
          contentType: application/json
          binder: rabbit1
          consumer:
            autoStartup: true
            concurrency: 2
            partitioned: false
            maxAttempts: 1
            bakOffInitialInterval: 1000
            backOffMaxInterval: 10000
            instanceCount: -1
            instanceIndex: -1
            batchMode: true
```

when i make every single message exception on purpose。i batched consume 5 messages then, deadLetterQueue also got nothing

```
2022-08-22 14:47:42.002|ERROR|juno2repeat-queue-test-1|250|o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler  :org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionToDestinationBinder$1@fb32b8b]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JSON parse failure,message:43444, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=[[B@1387d31], headers={skip-input-type-conversion=false, id=0f4259c1-1869-7553-b465-8cb6b0023842, amqp_batchedHeaders=[{amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=NON_PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=juno2repeat-queue-test, amqp_receivedExchange=, amqp_deliveryTag=5, amqp_consumerQueue=juno2repeat-queue-test, amqp_redelivered=false, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-AZ7DrBYVdo20G6LbsCviog}], contentType=application/json, timestamp=1661150862000}]
    at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:191)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:65)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:216)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.access$1500(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$BatchListener.onMessageBatch(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:481)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1653)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1576)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1564)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1559)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1499)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.executeWithList(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1055)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:939)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:84)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1316)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1222)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JSON parse failure,message:43444
    at com.gildata.dedupe.consumer.NoticeSCSConsumer.dedupeNotice(NoticeSCSConsumer.java:102)
    at com.gildata.dedupe.consumer.NoticeSCSConsumer.lambda$fundNotice$0(NoticeSCSConsumer.java:62)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.invokeConsumer(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:987)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.doApply(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:716)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.apply(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:562)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.PartitionAwareFunctionWrapper.apply(PartitionAwareFunctionWrapper.java:84)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionWrapper.apply(FunctionConfiguration.java:790)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionToDestinationBinder$1.handleMessageInternal(FunctionConfiguration.java:622)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56)
    ... 25 more

2022-08-22 14:47:42.003|ERROR|juno2repeat-queue-test-1|1464|o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer:Execution of Rabbit message listener failed, and the error handler threw an exception
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException: Error Handler converted exception to fatal
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler.handleError(ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler.java:146)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeErrorHandler(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1461)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.handleListenerException(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1745)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1520)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.executeWithList(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1055)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:939)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:84)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1316)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1222)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1768)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1661)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1576)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1564)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1559)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1499)
    ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: failed to send Message to channel 'juno2repeat-queue-test.errors'; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to org.springframework.amqp.core.Message
    at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInDeliveryExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:166)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:339)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendErrorMessageIfNecessary(MessageProducerSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:219)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.access$1500(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$BatchListener.onMessageBatch(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:481)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1653)
    ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to org.springframework.amqp.core.Message
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.rabbit.RabbitMessageChannelBinder$2.handleMessage(RabbitMessageChannelBinder.java:712)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.invokeHandler(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:222)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.dispatch(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:178)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317)
... 21 common frames omitted
```

Comment: is there anyone who used deadLetterQueue and batchMode at the same time?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69740749/spring-cloud-stream-rabbit-binder-error-sending-batch-messages-to-dlq

Comment: As that answer says, DLQ is not supported for batch listeners.